# Pagination in custom post type page template

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, pagination

I made a query for my custom post type "websites". I'm trying to get the pagination working but I'm running in some errors. I think the whole code is ok, only the part just before the end while tags. I just don't know how to get this right. Any help would be enormously appreciated!

```
<?php

        // WP_Query arguments
        $args = array (
            'post_type'              => 'website',
            'post_status'            => 'publish',
            'pagination'             => true,
            'posts_per_page'         => '5',
            'posts_per_archive_page' => '5',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
            'order'                  => 'DESC',
        );


        // Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
        $mfs_query['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

        // The Query
        $mfs_query = new WP_Query( $args );

        // Pagination fix
        $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query   = NULL;
        $wp_query   = $mfs_query;

        // The Loop
        if ( $mfs_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $mfs_query->have_posts() ) {
                $mfs_query->the_post();
                // do something

                ?> <div class="submission">

                    <a class="submission-thumb" href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>">
                        <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </a>

                    <a class="submission-title" href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3> <span class="posted-ago"><?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?></span>
                    </a>

                    <a class="submission-link" href="<?php the_field('site_url'); ?>" target="_blank">Visit</a>

                </div>

                <?php } ?>  
                <?php endwhile; else : ?> 

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>

            <?php // Custom query loop pagination
            previous_posts_link( 'Older Posts' );
            next_posts_link( 'Newer Posts', $mfs_query->max_num_pages ); ?>


            <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp_query;?>

            ?>
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to use a normal post type archive with a standard loop? Then the pagination would work out  of the box. You can use `pre_get_posts`  to modify it so that it only shows 5 per page, and you can change the URL of the archive using the `rewrite` parameter when registering the CPT. Replacing the main query with a whole new query is super wasteful and causes lots of problems ( usually pagination but others too )

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the code you have write in `archive-{post_type}.php` file or you can use ajax pagination

if you need to use page template:
Add this `'has_archive' => 'page template'` when you register the custom post type

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I think there's also something wrong with my code because I get a syntax error. The problem excists somewhere in the endwhile; else : part of the code I guess.

Comment: @fabrikgrafik just replace `<?php endwhile; else : ?>` with `<?php } ?>`

Comment: thank you, but I think I still need the endwhile else because now after my loop output I get "Sorry, no posts ...". And also after that I get: "Newer Posts ?>". So still a little mistake  there. Also pagination is not working ... I have added "has archive" to my CPT register but no difference. I have page-websites.php and also archive-websites.php to be sure and none works ..

Thanks again for your help, I am clueless and trying to learn how this works.